# are irradiation food still being sold

Tags: eggs, wheat

I've heard online that some irradiated food is still being sold and  I want some to confirm it with a yes or no and some evidence to prove it

Comment: This might be better asked on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/, if you have references for "heard online".

Comment: This is about shopping and maybe health - not cooking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about cooking or food preparation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FDA provides a logo](http://www.epa.gov/rpdweb00/sources/food_labeling.html) that is required for any irradiated products that are sold to consumers, which certainly implies that there are some foods being sold that have been processed.

Note that food sold by a restaurant using irradiated ingredients does not have to be labeled, but the wholesale packaging for the ingredients would.

Comment: Note that this just means that the food was treated with radiation. The food does not become radioactive, and despite the labeling, there's not likely to be a significant difference between it and food treated any other way, particularly not a culinary one.

Comment: Heck, if you want to get pedantic about it, microwaving could be considered a form of irradiation.

Comment: I do want to get pedantic. Cooking on a charcoal grill could be considered a form of irradiation.

Comment: More specifically, it means treated with *ionizing* radiation. No matter how pedantic you want to be, microwaves and grills don't produce ionizing radiation, and don't produce irradiated food.